# Retrieving All Tasks "CLOSED" Inside a Time Interval

Tags: org-mode

**Question:** How can I retrieve, over a set of files `S` (in particular: over my agenda files + their archive files) all org-mode headers that are marked "CLOSED" (i.e., have a "CLOSED" stamp like `CLOSED: [2019-05-11 Sat 18:11]`), so that I may then run an operation over them? My particular use case is to grab all headers that satisfy the above property, so that I can then grab each of their org-property `:T:`, and sum them together. So for example if I have

```
# File1
* SATISFICED Header1
  CLOSED: [2019-05-01 Wed 18:13]
:PROPERTIES:
:T: 1
:END:

# File2
* SATISFICED Header2
  CLOSED: [2019-05-11 Sat 18:13]
:PROPERTIES:
:T: 2
:END:
* SATISFICED Header3
  CLOSED: [2019-05-11 Sat 18:13]
:PROPERTIES:
:T: 3
:END:
```

I'd like to run a function like `(sum--all-T-from "[2019-05-10]" "[2019-05-11]")` to get as answer `5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a predicate function to determine whether the closed timestamp is within the specified range. If it is and the headline contains a T property, add the value of T to the list and return the sum of all numbers in the list.

```el
(defun timestamp-within-range-p (start-date end-date ts)
  "Non-nil if TS is within START-DATE and END-DATE."
  (or (and (time-less-p
        (org-time-string-to-time start-date)
        (org-time-string-to-time ts))
       (time-less-p
        (org-time-string-to-time ts)
        (org-time-string-to-time end-date)))
      (equal (format-time-string "[%F]" (org-time-string-to-time ts))
         start-date)
      (equal (format-time-string "[%F]" (org-time-string-to-time ts))
         end-date)))

(defun sum--all-T-from (start-date end-date)
  (let (closed)
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (when (and (assoc "CLOSED" (org-entry-properties))
                  (org-entry-get nil "T"))
         (let ((ts (assoc-default "CLOSED" (org-entry-properties))))
           (when (timestamp-within-range-p start-date end-date ts)
             (push (string-to-number (org-entry-get nil "T")) closed)))))
     nil 'agenda-with-archives)
    (apply '+ closed)))
```