# Retrieving a view of org-mode tasks completed within a range and that have a non-nil property

Tags: org-mode

How can I retrieve, over an elisp list of files `list-of-files`, a view of all org-mode headers that (i) were CLOSED in between `start` and `end` such that (ii) these headers have a property `P` defined (that isn't nil)?

Comment: What do you mean by "a view of all org-mode headers". Do you want a list of headline titles matching these conditions? Please explain.

Comment: I meant an agenda view. Should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Again you need a [function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50464/21533) to determine whether the closed timestamp is within the specified range. Now add the following to your agenda command to skip all entries not matching those conditions:

```
(org-agenda-skip-function
 (lambda ()
   (let ((ts (assoc-default "CLOSED" (org-entry-properties))))
     (unless (and (org-entry-get nil "P")
                  (timestamp-within-range-p "[2019-01-01]" "[2019-05-15]" ts))
       (save-excursion (outline-next-heading) (point))))))
```